# Site-only or Global Moderators? + Moderator privileges?

Tags: support, moderators

Out of curiosity, I'm just asking if a moderator is global or site-based. In other words, will a moderator only moderate a specific site or moderate all SE sites? And is there any privileges for moderators (e.g. Gain lots of reputation instantly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diamond mods are elected or appointed on one site. They got the diamond only on this site.

Those who have diamonds on all the sites are community managers, developers, or other SE employees (some of employees have the diamond only on this site - MSE, and some are not given diamonds at all).

As for getting reputation, there is no difference between mods and usual users. But mods have all the possible [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) regardless of their rep.

Comment: There are some exceptions to the "mods have all privileges" part, but they're technicalities that don't come up in practice. For example, a moderator with less than 5 reputation still can't post to child meta.

Comment: @Anna really can't post on child metas with less than 5 reps? Why? Thats strange...

Comment: Child metas require 5 reputation on the main site. It literally never happens that a community moderator would be below that, but it's still true that having a diamond doesn't override that check. Fun fact.

Comment: @Adam just curious, what about protected questions? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I *think* a diamond trumps that, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @AdamLear well, easy enough to check - create a sock with 1 rep, give it dianond and try to answer protected question. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Or... I could just look at the code. Don't have time right now, though.