# Can a moderator close my question as duplicate?

Tags: support

I know a moderator of stackexchange sites has some special Privileges to close a question as off topic.
For example ,the following  question

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746607/php-mysql-form-phpmya

  on stackoverflow was put on hold by  **[Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell)** a stackoverflow moderator with 21K reps, but he doesn't have a Golden badge or 1k votes on any of his answer related tags.

My question here is : Can He close my question my question as duplicate with mod privilegs?

Comment: Why close as a duplicate when the question is junk?

Comment: Shall we interpret "Can He" literally or as rhetoric way of asking "Should he be allowed to do that"? In the first case yes since he did, and in the second case yes since he's entitled to.

Comment: It's not closed as duplicate. It's closed as off topic. Friendly tip: read banners more carefully. That aside, the question you  linked to is just bad. No idea why you oppose closing it.

Comment: But obviously, otherwise moderator is not a *moderator*.

Comment: I really don't get what you're trying to ask. You think that moderator can close as off topic, but not as duplicate? In this case, this has already been asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251119/do-moderators-still-have-binding-close-votes-for-duplicate-questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes.

Diamond moderators (people whose names have a ♦ after them) have access to *every* privilege and power on the site.

They also have some additional powers, such as binding (one-vote) close and delete votes. That's what happened here.

Comment: Just a funny note: all the privileges except of 5 rep which is required to post on per-site meta. If a mod doesn't have 5 rep, they won't be able to post there (was told this at some point by Adam Lear) :)

Comment: @nicael funny indeed, what about answering protected questions? :)

Comment: @Sha Haha, don't know about this one :D

Comment: Btw, [found Adam's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244689/site-only-or-global-moderators-moderator-privileges/244691#comment799880_244691).